# Change the subject and title in docusign decline email

Tags: xml, email, docusignapi

[Docusign decline email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5nJy.png)

Our firm uses API to send information to DocuSign and we use our firm-specific branding for all the outgoing communications like emails etc. For the emails, we have configured the 'email resource file' to our firm's standard. I am trying to change the wordings in 'Decline' email that is triggered when a signer declines to sign the envelope using 'Other Actions - decline to sign' or using the 'decline tab'. I called DS support and they said they cant answer my question.

I have downloaded the email resource file XML from the admin account and was able to make certain changes to text however I am not able to change the email subject and the title. Could someone please help me. See 'DocuSign decline email' for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to update the subject earlier because I was using 3 years old version of resource file. Once I started using version 1.1, I am able to update the subject.

This can be done by subject node in the DocuSign resource file. The subject node is right after the main nodes for a type of Email. For e.g., for account activation, you'll see 3 nodes in resource file. 1st node will be HTML mail, 2nd will be for plain text and 3rd will be to manage the subject.